# How can I disable checkout date from check in date?

Tags: javascript, date, checkout, disable, checkin

I have wrote a program that shows check in and checkout date. Working well but it can only disable past date. here is my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mindate = new Date();
  $("#checkin").datepicker({
    showAnim: 'drop',
    numberOfMonth: 1,
    minDate: mindate,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    onclose: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
  });
  $("#checkout").datepicker({
    showAnim: 'drop',
    numberOfMonth: 1,
    minDate: mindate,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    onclose: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#checkin").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="checkin">
<input type="text" id="checkout">
```

here id the image bellow:
[image]

How can I disable checkout date from the value of check in date.

Answer (score 1):

Use [onSelect](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) transform it to [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) add one day if **#checkin** and remove one day if **#checkout** ,
use maxDate for **#checkin**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mindate = new Date();
  $("#checkin").datepicker({
    showAnim: 'drop',
    numberOfMonth: 1,
    minDate: mindate,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      let date = new Date(selectedDate);
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      $("#checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
    }
  });
  $("#checkout").datepicker({
    showAnim: 'drop',
    numberOfMonth: 1,
    minDate: mindate,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      let date = new Date(selectedDate);
      date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
      $("#checkin").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="checkin">
<input type="text" id="checkout">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable response. I already fix it but I learned more from this solution.